# Bokeh showing up blank when Tabs included

Tags: python, bokeh

I am working on an OHLC graph example in Bokeh, which I got to work originally. Now I'm trying to set it up with a DateRangeSlider in a separate column but I can't get anything to show up.

I know the current code doesn't actually connect the DateRangeSlider to change dates and that's fine. I just want it to show up properly.

I feel like the problem is coming up in the tabs part of the code.

I've been editing the code and the current error code I'm getting is:

> Error running application handler
>   : expected an element of List(Instance(Panel)), got seq
>   with invalid items [Figure(id='1005', ...)]

Code Below:

```
#import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import show,figure, output_file
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider, Tabs, Panel
from bokeh.layouts import layout, column, row, WidgetBox

df = pd.read_csv("adbe.csv", parse_dates = ["Date"])

def OHLC_tab(df):

    #output_file("stockOHLChistory.html")

    start_date = df["Date"].min()
    end_date = df["Date"].max()

    #add to the DF
    df["Change"] = (df["Close"] / df["Open"] - 1) * 100
    df["Change"] = df["Change"].apply(lambda x: str(round(x,2)) + "%")

    #convert dates to sequence
    seqs = np.arange(df.shape[0])
    df["seq"] = pd.Series(seqs)

    #convert dates for hover
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
    df["displaydate"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m/%d'))

    def make_plot():
        active_dates = df.Date.between(start_date, end_date)
        inc = df.Close > df.Open
        dec = df.Open > df.Close

        print(list(df.columns))

        sourceInc=ColumnDataSource(df[inc])
        sourceDec=ColumnDataSource(df[dec])

        w = 18 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        p = figure(plot_height = 500, plot_width = 600, 
                   x_axis_type = "datetime", 
                   sizing_mode = 'scale_both')

        hover = HoverTool(names = ['upbars', 'downbars'],
                          tooltips = [("Date: ", "@displaydate"),
                                     ("Open: ", "@Open"),
                                     ("Close: ", "@Close"),
                                     ("Change: ","@Change")])

        p.add_tools(hover)

        p.vbar('Date', w, 'Open', 'Close', source = sourceInc, 
               fill_color = "green", line_color = "green", name = 'upbars')
        p.vbar('Date', w, 'Open', 'Close', source = sourceDec, 
               fill_color = "red", line_color = "red", name = 'downbars')
        p.segment(df.Date[inc], df.High[inc], df.Date[inc], 
                  df.Low[inc], color = "green")
        p.segment(df.Date[dec], df.High[dec], df.Date[dec], 
                  df.Low[dec], color = "red")

        p = style(p)

        print(p.title.text)

        return p

    def style(p):
        p.title.text = "Stock History"
        p.xaxis.axis_label = "Date"
        p.yaxis.axis_label = "Price"

        return p

    date_select = DateRangeSlider(start = start_date, end = end_date, step = 1,
                                  title = "Date Range", width = 250)

    p = make_plot()

    p = style(p)

    controls = WidgetBox(date_select)

    layout = row(controls, p)

    tab1 = Panel(child = layout, title = "History")

    return p

tab = OHLC_tab(df)

tabs = Tabs(tabs = [tab])

curdoc().title = "Does this work?"
curdoc().add_root(tabs)

print(curdoc().title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `OHLC_tab` function is returning the plot, not the `Panel` for the tabs You presumably want:

```
def OHLC_tab(df):

    ...

    return tab1
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but that still didn't solve the problem. The screen is still blank. The title does show up though. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Without a complete example script to actually run and investigate, I can't really speculate more.